# How add gradient shadow for UIImage

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need add shadow how in this image -[image]

I know  in unity3d exist one method for add shadow but, it is not with gradiently, when I added shader with 3 colors, alpha not transformed in transparent...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK Unity does not come with anything like this integrated by default.

You can use a third-party plugin:

- For text, use **[TextMeshPro](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/beta-projects/textmesh-pro-84126)**. It is not included/integrated with unity 
  by default, but it has been officially acquired by unity and so, is (now) 
  completely free.
- For other UI elements, such as images, I don't know of any plugin
  that does this; primarily because I don't use any, because of the
  alternative below.
- You can also easily do this statically with custom images. You can easily 
  apply this effect in Photoshop or pretty much any decent image-editing 
  software, and then use that in your game/app just like you would any other image.

Comment: Thanks, I thought maybe exist in unity3d  any plugins but ... if it does not exist .. it remains to use Photoshop ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with basic rounded shapes, I have made a package that can do these shapes and has a fallOff feature. It can give you the desired look without any textures. The fallOff can be animated in realtime if you want.

Assetstore Link: [Procedural UI Image](http://u3d.as/mYk)